# Could not save change database in Session_Start() of Global.asax in asp.net MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to record the client that browse my web page, So I do this in Session_Start() of Global.asax

```
    String ipAddress = System.Web. HttpContext.Current.Request.
                       ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    Web.Models.WebsiteTracking web_track = new  Web.Models.WebsiteTracking();
    web_track.IDUser = 0;
    web_track.ActiveLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
    web_track.IPAddress = ipAddress;

    this.DataContext.WebsiteTrackings.AddObject(web_track);
    this.DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

I record the user's IP address,the date that they browse and ID = 0 to table WebsiteTracking. But It error : Does not contain definition DataContext and no extend method 'DataContext'.

Anyone can tell me, which thing that I have to replace with "this.DataContext".

Thanks you so much.

Comment: `this` in the `Session_Start` method refers to the `HttpApplication`; unless you have replaced that, there is no property `DataContext`, need more info on what you are trying to do, etc.

Comment: I want to save the record to the database. In my model I use " public class CustomerModels : ItemEntityDataContext" , so I can write this.DataContext , But in the block of code below I don't know how to verify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a new instance of your `DataContext`.

```
String ipAddress = System.Web. HttpContext.Current.Request.
                   ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
Web.Models.WebsiteTracking web_track = new  Web.Models.WebsiteTracking();
web_track.IDUser = 0;
web_track.ActiveLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
web_track.IPAddress = ipAddress;

using(var dataContext = new DataContext())
{
    dataContext.WebsiteTrackings.AddObject(web_track);
    dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: It error : The type or namespace 'Datacontext' could not be found.

Comment: @socheata Then replace `DataContext` with your actual context name.